# Why my view controller modal presented animation is slow on some devices?

Tags: ios, swift

I still cant figure out why my modally presented view controller presentation animation is slow on iphone 5 or ipad or some device which got lower cpu ? When i tried to run on iPhone 6 and simulator,it presented normally and smooth well.But,when I tested on iPad Mini 1 and iPhone 5,it appear after 2 or 3 second later.Any help with animation speed?

Here is my Advance Search View which is presented as modally when I click navigation left bar button.

[image: Advance Search View]

Was it because I used a lot of UI components such as `UIPickerView`,`UIDatePicker`,`UITextField`,`UISegmentControl` or Static Table Cell?

Or there is something wrong with my viewDidLoad() method where I initialize many array for `UIPickerView` objects?

Comment: What is the mock up tool you are using? Just interesting of it. It looks nice.

Comment: Just Xcode 6.4,By setting view controller simulated size to "Freeform".

Answer (score 2):

u have delay because to manny objects must be initialized in `viewdidload`. U can repace some code to `viewDidApear`.

or u can try initialized u objects in background threed like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

             // initialize objects
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where the Time Profiler will help.

1. In the Xcode menu bar, choose Product->Profile.
2. Choose the Time Profiler from the menu that appears.
3. Click the record button in the upper left and perform the actions that seem slower then they should be.
4. Have a look at the output. Checking "Hide system libraries" on the right can help you find things that you have control over.

Now you should have a better idea of what is taking the device so long.